# \begin{table} makes table disappear. (pdflatex)

Tags: tables

I'm currently using pdflatex. Several times, some sections of my work would not get displayed at all when compild to pdf. For e.g., the following code works:

```
\begin{center}
    {\footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 
     \hline
     {H} & {V}  \\ 
     \hline \hline
     F & 0.3, 0.5, 0.7 \\ 
     N & 5, 10, 15, 20 \\
     O & 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 \\
     T r & 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.99 \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{center}
```

But this won't work:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline & & &  \\
        Test users  &  Operating system & Browser & Screen resolution\\ 
& & &  \\ \hline
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test environment details}
    \label{Test-environment-details}
\end{table}
```

How do I figure out what the problem is ? If there is a warning at least I can work on that. Please help. (I'm a noob to latex btw)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A table is a float, are you sure that it did not just float somewhere? We won't be able to tell unless you provide a complete minimal working example, i.e. a minimal document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates the issue.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "But this won't work". For what it's worth, your code compiles fine if I sandwich it between `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}` and `\end{document}` instructions. Incidentally, I would replace the three instances of `X` in the fourth column with `$\times$`.

Comment: latex will not drop a table without warning (it probably also warned about the use of `[!h]`, are you sure the table hasn't just been moved to another page (that is the only purpose of the `table` environment.  add `\listoftables` to the document and run latex twice and there will be a list printed at the start saying which page each table is on (that is why tables have captions)

Comment: You could try to use \begin{table}[htb!] ...